# How to iterate through a list of object on timer_tick event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, random

I have a list

`static List<Participants> soop = ParticipantRepository.GetAllParticipants();`

It has some 800 items. Then there's a `label` and a `timer`. At `timer_tick`, I want to display one of the items randomly. Here's the code for that event

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            foreach (var participants in soop)
            {
                a = participants.RollNumber;
                label1.Text = a;
                break;
            }
            counter++;
            if (counter == 200) {
                timer1.Stop();
                pictureBox5.Visible = false;
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
```

I have not been able to achieve the random functionality so far because only one RollNumber is being displayed and then the timer takes its time and runs out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the random class.

```
    Random randomGen = new Random();
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var i = randomGen.Next(0, soop.Count);
        label1.Text = soop[i].RollNumber;

        counter++;
        if (counter == 200)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            pictureBox5.Visible = false;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For better randomness, you should store `randomGen` in a field

Comment: @KevinGosse, what does better randomness mean? Elimination of repetition or what?

Comment: @fasihullahkhan In reality the `Random` class doesn't really give you random numbers. So in theory, if you create 2 separate classes of `Random` directly after each other, they will give you the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: Edit: you are right, of course. To avoid the "repeating of randomness", I moved out the instance creation to global variable.

Comment: `The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code` is what I get if move `var` out.

Answer (score 0):

At each tick the `timer1_Tick` is called, so your `foreach` loop starts back from the beginning and you end up displaying the first item every time. Instead, you can store the index of the last item you displayed. You already have `counter` so let's use it:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    label1.Text = soop[counter % soop.Count].RollNumber;

    counter++;
    if (counter == 200) {
        timer1.Stop();
        pictureBox5.Visible = false;
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do I make this iteration random?

Comment: But it is not really random, which item will be taken.

Comment: @fasihullahkhan if you need it to be random, see Mailor's answer